# How to add custom button in SSRS report viewer to download custom report?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportviewerformvc

I have report viewer which will load data from parameterized stored procedure. The result will be multiple column or single column also.  I need to add custom button in report viewer to download the output as my own specific xml format.

I can't use inbuild xml export because it has its own tag appended before data.

Is there any way to achieve this? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can just create a URL in the report that links to a pre-rendered XML file to be downloaded.

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, where to create a url and I do not have any pre-rendered xml.